# FB OAuth failed while log in Meteor Cordova app

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, meteor, oauth

I have tried many hours to make the Meteor Cordova app work, but the OAuth still failed while log in. It may because the setting of ROOT_URL in app and Facebook. How to set them to let FB log in work in local Cordova app? (my localhost:3000 web app works)

The Cordova browser url is:

```
http://155.41.71.227:3000/_oauth/facebook?close&code=AQD8V1BBVegRw_xXK3g_f9AwV0IpB0k_DljuNhzxGTEbztaO47C_drvfM0CeLx_hLgjEMChUdrIjCUOjerMu67RfbDOFF003LXPXbJU0eEl8ENt6kw5biVIkWxvkQynZuk8W-fSpHFJCYyjzYAM8zg2L84nREj3wYJnaTb9u-u7SoSBz736Spjc9JSCqxRMvLjLX4cEcjLyNx07DDxPJLxo7TS8yicpwVLlHvXSTNYTa7O5lasFQ3szcUwCT6cCawK9g8mxzJgsFLtD_PcxnTNYvwUDr1NaoUCcKBrs39phgb13ogdcdaasT6h85JuZd8_hbntR9PwYjKT9tWxMBIauo&state=eyJsb2dpblN0eWxlIjoicG9wdXAiLCJjcmVkZW50aWFsVG9rZW4iOiJudXZpel81eG1jcjhlVktSeVVMZE9aMFgtNmtJWVpXZk51WHZSTnBvMmtEIiwiaXNDb3Jkb3ZhIjp0cnVlfQ%3D%3D#_=_
```

The server side error is:

```
Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook.
failed [400] {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. 
Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the 
OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,
"fbtrace_id":"F28LmOCPwyL"}}
```

My setting of FB in PRODUCTS->Facebook Login:
[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: Someone got this issue too here. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8296

Comment: Fwiw, we never did get it working and gave up on it. I forget the exact issue, one of my devs was the one working on it.

Comment: Pop-up doesn't show because, obviously, login failed. I don't know about FB implementation but I'm pretty sure in OAuth2 there supposed to be redirect_uri in your query, like, `&redirect_uri=http://155.41.71.227:3000`

Comment: As the error message says, the `redirect_uri` parameter value passed to the endpoint where the code gets exchanged for a token, must match the value that was used when the login dialog was called.

Answer (score 0):

I could partially fix this error.

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri
>   is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

This is avoided by setting the *`$ROOT_URL`* environment variable with the redirect URL value set in the Facebook Login settings. WIth that I'm still getting the same blank UIWebView without closing behaviour but, at least, when I tap the Done button, the user is logged in on my app.

I'm going to keep working on a solution for this, as I'm just a few days ahead the launch of our app. If someone finds a solution for this, please let us know. I'll appreciate it